# Reading a server file to the browsers save dialog

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a select element on a WordPress page that contains several .txt files that reside on the server.  When I select one of the files from the select drop down I would like the file to be downloaded to the browser, activating the browser's save dialog.

One way to do the download would be  to have the files be in links that are clicked, instead of option elements in a select drop down. I could do something like:

```
<a href="/directory/file1.txt download> file1.txt  </a>
```

But then the user would have to select from a bunch of links instead of being able to select an option from the dropdown.    And I don't see a way to get a select choice from the drop down to execute a link like above.

I could also have a change handler in jQuery that sensed a drop down selection and then passed the selection up to PHP with an jQuery ajax post call and executed something in PHP like:

```
<?php
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment");
   header("Content-Type: text/plain"); 
   readfile("/directory/file1.txt");
?>
```

But if I reached PHP through an ajax call I'm not sure the

```
<?php
       header("Content-Disposition: attachment");
       header("Content-Type: text/plain"); 
       readfile("/directory/file1.txt");
    ?>
```

would connect to the browser or, instead, just pass data back to the ajax call.

Does anyone see the best way to trigger the download from a select choice?

Thanks

=====

Comment: I'm pretty sure your solution will work as you expect

Comment: I tried the php header/readfile solution but the data comes back as the first parameter in the Ajax success function, rather than being downloaded to the browser, as I was afraid.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually misread your solution... I still think your solution is ok, you just need to set top.location.href to point to the PHP script instead of accessing it via ajax. The browser will prompt the download because you set content-disposition:attachment header, and the current window should stay the same.

Comment: Could you provide an example using top.location.href? The PHP script is get_feed.php.  Also if you put your solution in an answer I'll choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that I didn't test all the setup, but I tested the proposed solution of using top.location.href to trigger the download without leaving the current page, and it works.

Ok so assuming you are using jQuery, you need three things:

1- the dispenser script:

```
<?php
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment");
   header("Content-Type: text/plain"); 
   readfile('/directory/'.$_GET['filename']);
?>
```

(this should be reachable at the url `http://www.yourdomain.com/get_feed.php` and takes a parameter `filename` --- please if you use something like this add checks and possibly a whitelist to make sure the script can't be abused to access other files on the server that you don't want to be accessible; the script directly using a parameter is VERY unsafe)

2- an html select dropdown in your page with the list of urls you want to reach, such as:

```
<select id="the-dropdown">
    <option value="">Choose a file...</option>
    <option value="http://www.yourdomain.com/get_feed.php?filename=file1.txt">file1.txt</option>
    <option value="http://www.yourdomain.com/get_feed.php?filename=file2.txt">file2.txt</option>
</select>
```

and 3- a snippet of js such as:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#the-dropdown').change(function() {
            var that = $(this);
            if (that.val() !== '') {
                top.location.href = that.val();
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And that's it.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't mean for you to go to all that trouble, but I appreciate it.